# Implement scripting.dictionary item

Tags: excel, vba, windows-scripting

I'm trying to create a class that inherits `Scripting.Dictionnary` to create hash tables with type restrictive keys and items.

The problem I encounter is that I don't find any documentation about how to implement this, and I have an error message telling me I must implement Item to interface dictionary.

Here is the prototype of my class :

```
Option Explicit
Implements Dictionary

Public Sub Add(nom As String, jour As Date, temps As Integer)
    Supplier.Add nom, Array(jour, temps)
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(Key As String) As Array
    Item = Supplier.Item(Key)
End Property

Public Property Set Item(Key As String, jour As Date, temps As Integer)
    Set Supplier.Item(Key) = Array(jour, temps)
End Property
```

How should I Implement `Item` to make it work ? And is this the good way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: For your item property the number of parameters should match for the let and get statements.  In your case you have two parameters for the get (string and variant array) and three for the let (string,date and integer).  So your tactics should be to move the array to be a parameter in the let statement 'Set Item (Key as string, ArrayItem as variant) '.  You also need to change your get to 'as variant' from 'as array'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stated goal is to implement a strongly-typed Dictionary.  To accomplish this goal, I would not implement an Interface.  Rather, I would wrap the Dictionary in a class and achieve the strong-typing by using another class:

**Supplier Class**

```
Option Explicit

Private Supplier As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set Supplier = New Dictionary
End Sub

Public Sub Add(Key As String, Item As SupplierItem)
   Supplier.Add Key, Item
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(Key As String) As SupplierItem
   Set Item = Supplier.Item(Key)
End Property

Public Property Set Item(Key As String, Value As SupplierItem)
   Set Supplier.Item(Key) = Value
End Property
```

**SupplierItem Class**

```
Option Explicit

Public jour As Date
Public temps As Integer
```

**Testing Logic**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
   Dim s As Supplier
   Dim si As SupplierItem
   
   Set s = New Supplier
   
   Set si = New SupplierItem
   si.jour = Now
   si.temps = 3
   s.Add "Key1", si
   Debug.Print s.Item("Key1").temps
   
   Set si = New SupplierItem
   si.jour = Now
   si.temps = 4
   Set s.Item("Key1") = si
   Debug.Print s.Item("Key1").temps
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to implement all the functions/properties of what you are implementing.

Something like so

```
Option Explicit

Private d As Scripting.Dictionary

Implements Scripting.Dictionary

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub

Public Property Set Dictionary_Item(Key As Variant, RHS As Variant)
    Set d.Item(Key) = RHS
End Property

Public Property Let Dictionary_Item(Key As Variant, RHS As Variant)
    d.Item(Key) = RHS
End Property

Public Property Get Dictionary_Item(Key As Variant) As Variant

End Property

Public Sub Dictionary_Add(Key As Variant, Item As Variant)

End Sub

Public Property Let Dictionary_CompareMode(ByVal RHS As Scripting.CompareMethod)

End Property

Public Property Get Dictionary_CompareMode() As Scripting.CompareMethod

End Property

Public Property Get Dictionary_Count() As Long

End Property

Public Function Dictionary_Exists(Key As Variant) As Boolean

End Function

Public Property Get Dictionary_HashVal(Key As Variant) As Variant

End Property

Public Function Dictionary_Items() As Variant

End Function

Public Property Let Dictionary_Key(Key As Variant, RHS As Variant)

End Property

Public Function Dictionary_Keys() As Variant

End Function

Public Sub Dictionary_Remove(Key As Variant)

End Sub

Public Sub Dictionary_RemoveAll()

End Sub
```

Comment: It should be noted that these methods can be generated by selecting `Dictionary` from the dropdown on the left and then each of the properties from the dropdown on the right.

Comment: Yes, @BrianMStafford, i forgot to add that.

Comment: It would also be reasonable to observe that if all that is required is to wrap a scripting.dictionary for use within a VBA project, so that the item method specifies a specific type (as indicated by the OP), then implementing the scripting.dictionary interface is the wrong approach as it limits the item method to Variant.